# I have not given any pointer but compiler says comparison between pointer and integer?

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-warnings

I am continuously getting that warning.
I am sharing my code , please see and tell where is pointer.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  int ageofUser, age;
  char damru[100], professionUser[20], name[20];

  printf("Hello I am Damroo , your personal chatbot.\n But I can answer limited questions because I am in developing phase.\n so lets chat.\n So , What is your name ?\n");
  scanf("%s", &damru);

  printf("Ohkay, what is your age ?");
  scanf("%d", &ageofUser);

  printf("Ohkay , Mr. %d , What do you work ?", &ageofUser);
  scanf("%s", &professionUser);

  printf("Why don't you talk bidirectionally ?");
  if (scanf("%s", &name) == "What is your name ?");
  printf("I am damroo.");

  if (scanf("%d", &age) == "what is your age ?");
  printf("I was born on 17/02/2021");

  return 0;
}
```

I just want to know where is pointer. I can't find any.

Comment: Here you are trying to use a pointer `printf("Ohkay , Mr. %d , What do you work ?", &ageofUser);` instead of an integer, remove the `&`.

Comment: Also your usage of  `scanf` is wrong. Read the documentation of `scanf` and fin out what the return value is. But anyway youf `if` have no effect here, because of the `;` at the end of the lines starting with `if`

Comment: Also, scanf returns the actual number of red elements. Comparing it to a string literal is never going to work: you may actually want to compare "age" char array with "What is your age ?", for example ,instead of the actual return value of scanf.

Comment: Your compiler should tell you where the error is. Then you can identify the involved operands. For example, `"what is your age ?"` is used as a pointer)

Comment: Detail: So if your user's age is 21, you address him as _"Mr. 21"_?

Comment: Like others said in the comments, you are also using `scanf()` the wrong way.

Comment: The root of the problem here is: you can't do programming by taking a chance at the syntax or by trial & error. You must actually understand what every single line you type does and how C actually works. Otherwise you will keep getting very strange errors and bugs that you have no idea where they are coming from.

Comment: Read about `strcmp`, `strncmp`, `strcasecmp` and similar.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) of `scanf(3)` says

> RETURN VALUE
>
> On success, these functions return the number of input items successfully matched
> and assigned; this can be fewer than provided
> for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

Thus, you cannot compare `scanf()` with a string. You need to use `strcmp()`:

```
char *str = "hello";
char *str_comp = "ello";

if (strcmp(str, str_comp) == 0) {
    // both are equal
} else {
    // otherwise, not
}
```

Note that you can compare a string constant directly.

For scanning the character arrays, don't introduce an ampersand sign in `scanf()`:

```
scanf("%s", professionUser); // removed &
```

Similarly, you never need to put an ampersand in `printf()`. To code defensively, always check the return values of `scanf()`, `fgets()`, etc.